# Eclipse i can not open folder structure

Tags: java, eclipse

In window Package Explorer I haven't any project(In workspace folder a have a few), I'm trying refresh view, but it's doesn't work, I dont know also how to open a whole project structure from this folder.

Comment: Check your workspace path under Window > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces, correct path displaying? You can also tick the "Promt for workspace on startup" checkbox, restart eclipse and switch to another directory.

Comment: @kevcodez You can switch to another directory while in Eclipse as well. You don't need to restart...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new project called *exactly* the same name as a project you already have. Maybe there is an easier way to do it, but this works just fine if you don't have 625520 projects.

Comment: Closely I import my project and it work,